Sheets : refresh an importxml regulary
I'm looking to refresh several importxmls on a regular basis (every minute or every 5 minutes). I'm using the script below with a linked trigger, set every minute. Despite this, the target cell only refreshes if I run the script manually. Do you have any idea of ​​the problem?
function getData() {
  var queryString = Math.random();

  var Xpath_1 = "//table[@class='detail']/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]";
  var importXpath_1 = '=IMPORTXML("' + 'https://www.matchendirect.fr/tennis/match-367934-c-gauff-t-zidansek' + '?' + queryString + '";"'+ Xpath_1 + '")';
  
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('S30').setValue(importXpath_1);
}

I'm trying to update the score of a match from a site on a sheet

You can try:
function getData() {
  var queryString = Math.random();

  var Xpath_1 = "//table[@class='detail']/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]";
  var importXpath_1 = '=IMPORTXML("https://www.matchendirect.fr/tennis/match-367934-c-gauff-t-zidansek?' + queryString + '","' + Xpath_1 + '")';

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange('S30').setValue(importXpath_1);
}

but keep in mind that there are limits: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/58515#zippy=%2Cchoose-how-often-formulas-calculate


It's the same result, i've test with this code to show that the result don't change with the trigger :
[code]
function getData2() {
var queryString = Math.random();
var Xpath_1 = "//div[@id='body_wrapper']/main/section[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div";
var importXpath_1 = '=IMPORTXML("'+'https://dayspedia.com/time/online' + '?' + queryString + '";"' + Xpath_1 + '")';
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
sheet.getRange('S30').setValue(importXpath_1);
}
[/code]
